# RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default':

Tags: database, postgresql, connection

RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': fe_sendauth: no password supplied warnings.warn (No changes detected)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You were using a Mysql DB and changed to PostGreSql, you gotta change your port to 5432...